# Multiple LEFT JOIN in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have the following SQL select:

```
SELECT s.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', m.type, m.id, m.filename) SEPARATOR ',') AS multimedia,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', c.id) SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
FROM sections s 


LEFT JOIN sections_multimedia sm
     ON s.id = sm.section_id 
LEFT JOIN multimedia m
     ON sm.multimedia_id = m.id 


LEFT JOIN sections_categories sc
     ON s.id = sc.section_id 
LEFT JOIN categories c
     ON sc.category_id = c.id


WHERE s.id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.position, s.id ASC;
```

As a result, the field 'categories' has the correct values, which are(2,3), but unfortunately repeated many times! (the result is: 2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)

What is wrong with my select?

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: your title says inner joins but your query is using left joins?

Comment: My mistake! I edited the title! Thank you!

Comment: What do you do with this result?

Comment: I have them into a php array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking for aggregates from different tables, you should always aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  mul.multimedia,
  cat.categories 
FROM sections s 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    sm.section_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', m.type, m.id, m.filename) SEPARATOR ',') AS multimedia
  FROM sections_multimedia sm
  JOIN multimedia m ON sm.multimedia_id = m.id 
  GROUP BY sm.section_id
) mul ON s.id = mul.section_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    sc.section_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', c.id) SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
  FROM sections_categories sc
  JOIN categories c ON sc.category_id = c.id
  GROUP BY sc.section_id
) cat ON s.id = cat.section_id;
```

Comment: This query seems to work better than the Gordon's answer which is right too! But is this the fastest query i could do to have the result? All i want to achieve, is select all the "sections" with all the multimedia and categories they belong! What is the fastest query i could run? because imagine if i will have 1.000.000 rows! Thank you!

Comment: @Nick . . . Which is faster depends on a lot of factors about your data and whether you have any additional filtering.

Comment: Without additional filtering and as it is now, what is the fastest way to select?

Comment: You want to select all data from all the tables and aggregate. There is little you can do to speed this up. The query should be fine as is. Which leaves you with DBA stuff (sectors, partitions, table space, ...? dunno; I am not a MySQL DBA), or you invest in hardware.

Answer (score 3):

You can get unique values by using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', m.type, m.id, m.filename) SEPARATOR ',') AS multimedia,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', c.id) SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
```

This is actually a work-around.  Your real problem is that multiple joins are creating a Cartesian product of value for each row in the result set.  It might be better to aggregate before doing the joins, rather than removing the duplicates when aggregating.

Comment: Dear Gordon, thank you for your prompt reply! How can i agreegate before doing the joins?

Comment: Oh, I read this after posting my answer. So Gordon and I hold the same opinion: aggregate before joining :-)